# how to disable schema validation in JAX-RS or remove ns2 from response on client side?

Tags: validation, jax-rs

3rd Party API had the following response created for my JAX-RS request:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<name xmlns="http://www.example.com/name">
    <first>John</first>
    <middle>M</middle>
    <last>Doe</last>
</name>
```

referring to this schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:target="http://www.example.com/name"
targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/name" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <element name="name">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element name="first" type="string"/>
                <element name="middle" type="string"/>
                <element name="last" type="string"/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </element>
</schema>
```

However , they changed the server response to this by mistake:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ns2:name xmlns:ns2="http://www.example.com/name">
    <first>John</first>
    <middle>M</middle>
    <last>Doe</last>
</ns2:name>
```

Now when I call the API using JAX-RS webclient, I have NOT null Response object , but the value inside it is all null as the child nodes of the XML response is not using namespace ns2.

How do I ignore namespace ns2? so the response object value will not be null.